# Mounted volume cannot be read

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am working on dockerizing our development environment for an application consisting of a React-TypeScript front, ASP.NET Core 2 back, SQL Server db.

I believe I am close to having this working, but I am running into an issue where the .NET core container cannot read or write to mounted volumes.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
proj
  docker-compose.yml
  .env
  -> src
     -> db
        -> obj
        -> build
           -> .sql files
           -> Dockerfile
     -> server
        -> .NET Core solution with many projects
        -> Dockerfile
     -> ui-client
        -> react app
        -> Dockerfile
```

The server/Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7

# .NET Core
# Register repository
RUN rpm -Uvh https://packages.microsoft.com/config/rhel/7/packages-microsoft-prod.rpm

# Install .NET Core and dependencies
RUN yum install -y dotnet-sdk-2.1

# Update and clean
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum clean all

# Configure Kestrel
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5001
ENV DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER true
ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER true
ENV NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE skip

# Reference the environment
VOLUME [ "/app", "/.keys", "/logs"]
```

Minimal .env example:

```
PROJ_KEYS=~/.keys/proj
PROJ_CERT=/.keys/cert.pem
PROJ_KEY=/.keys/proj.pfx
PROJ_KEY_PW=ThisIsAFakePassword
PROJ_LOGGING_DIR=~/work/logs
SERILOG_DIR=/logs
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:

  coreapi:
    build: ./src/server
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    depends_on:
      - mssql
    volumes:
      - ./src/server:/app
      - ${PROJ_KEYS}:/.keys
      - ${PROJ_LOGGING_DIR}:/logs
    environment:
      PROJ_CERT: ${PROJ_CERT}
      PROJ_KEY: ${PROJ_KEY}
      PROJ_KEY_PW: ${PROJ_KEY_PW}
      PROJ_LOG_DIR: ${SERILOG_DIR}
    working_dir: "/app/API"
    command: ["dotnet", "run"]
    networks:
      local:
        aliases:
          - coreapi
```

When I `docker-compose up` it is able to build all of the required images, but when the coreapi container starts I get this error:

```
coreapi_1  | Using launch settings from /app/API/Properties/launchSettings.json...
coreapi_1  | [18:58:22 INF] Starting Proj's API
coreapi_1  | [18:58:22 FTL] API terminated unexpectedly
coreapi_1  | System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/Users/<my_user>/.keys/proj/cert.pem'.
coreapi_1  |    at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
coreapi_1  |    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
coreapi_1  |    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
coreapi_1  |    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
coreapi_1  |    at System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(String path)
coreapi_1  |    at API.Options.ConfigExtensions.ConfigureProjOptions(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment environment) in /app/API/Options/ConfigExtensions.Options.cs:line 54
coreapi_1  |    at API.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in /app/API/Startup.cs:line 32
coreapi_1  | --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
coreapi_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
coreapi_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
coreapi_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
coreapi_1  |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
coreapi_1  |    at API.Program.Main(String[] args) in /app/API/Program.cs:line 33
proj_coreapi_1 exited with code 1
```

I've checked the permissions on the directory that I am mounting on the docker container.

`ls -la ~/.keys/proj` gives:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 my_user  staff   977 Jun 21 08:59 cert.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 my_user  staff  1704 Jun 21 08:59 key.pem
-rw-r--r--  1 my_user  staff  2285 Jun 21 09:00 proj.pfx
```

My guess is that I've got something entered incorrectly in either the docker-compose file or the .env file, but I'm confused as to how that could be if the error I'm getting points at the correct location of the file I'm trying to read.

Also of note, there is no log file being written when this fails even though it does write a log file when it fails out of container. Makes me think the logging volume is not configured correctly either.

How do I mount a folder as a volume on my container, so the application can use the keys in that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I had to change my `.env` file so I wasn't using existing environment variables on my system.

So in my `.env` file I had a variable named `PROJ_CERT=/.keys/cert.pem`, which collided with a variable in my `.bash_profile`.

I changed it to `CERT=...` and it is working now.